# Flexslider 2: how do I hide the direction-nav "prev" arrow for my initial slide?

Tags: flexslider

I'm playing around with the CSS and Javascript for Flexslider 2 and I can't figure out how to hide the "prev" arrow for only the initial slide of my slide show. I would like it to then reappear for the remainder of the slideshow.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Case

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same boat

Answer (score 6):

I love the flexslider because you can write custom jquery logic within it's callback functions.  Here is a basic example of hiding the arrows  by default, then on click (a jquery method), reveal them again, all within the flexslider start() callback function...

```
$('#carousel-home').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 170,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider',
    start:function(slider){
        //HIDE THE ARROWS BY DEFAULT...
        $('#slider .flex-direction-nav').css({visibility:'hidden'});

        //THEN INSERT YOUR CUSTOM JQUERY CLICK ACTIONS TO REVEAL THEM AGAIN
        slider.find('a').on('click',function(){
        $('#slider .flex-direction-nav').css({visibility:'visible'});
        });
    }//end start function
});//end carousel

$('#slider').flexslider({
    slidshow: false,
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: true,
    sync: "#carousel-home"
});//end slider
```

That will go along with the following HTML...

```
<div id="carousel-home" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides ffastandards">
  <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Voice</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="slider" class="flexslider content-slider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li>mission</li>
    <li>vision</li>
    <li>voice</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Flexslider adds a class of `'flex-disabled'` to the corresponding navigation elements upon reaching the beginning or end of the slideshow/carousel.

Looks like this only works if you set this parameter: `animationLoop: false`.

You can use this class to hide the 'prev' arrow (or 'next' arrow).

```
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-disabled {
   display:none;
}
```

Optionally, you could set the opacity along with a CSS transition to have it fade in/out.

```
.flex-direction-nav a {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .3s;
   -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-disabled {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next, 
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: The question asked for a way to hide the "prev" arrow on the first slide only. This css will hide the arrows for every slide.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: 'fade',
                controlsContainer: '.flexslider',
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav:false
            });
```

This is the solution, add directionNav:false

Answer (score 0):

Add some conditional statements that add ie8 to your pages html tag. Then add this to the stylesheet

```
html.ie8 .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev, html.ie8 .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {display:none;}

html.ie8 #flexslider_hg_homepage_wrapper:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev,
html.ie8 #flexslider_hg_homepage_wrapper:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this code in your javascript file:
       $('your .class or #id').flexslider({
           controlNav: true
         });